# How can I quickly see parsing errors in my chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can use chrome's "inspect element" feature to view and debug my javascript, but only if it has successfully loaded. If the script has a parsing error then it doesn't load and isn't shown via "inspect element".

How can I get chrome to show me its attempt to parse my script and a list of errors it has encountered?

I'm a newb to both chrome extensions and javascript, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toolbar at the top of the Web Inspector (the window/pane that pops up when you "Inspect Element") click on the right-most button/tab, "Console," as seen here:

[image: Web Inspector - Console]

Not only will this show you all of the errors the page generates (JavaScript and others), it's also a full JavaScript REPL so you can interact with the page by entering any JavaScript you want.

Comment: bingo! Thanks Jordan, nice screenshot too.

Answer (score 0):

Jordan has the right answer (should have seen that, I knew it was a newb question!), but while I was searching I also came across [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), which is quite useful. It's stricter than the chrome execution engine, so it generates a bunch of warnings you may not need to worry about, but still handy.